# Deactivate cascade records in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have three custom entities: A, B and C

> |A| **1** --------- **N** |B| **1** --------- **N** |C|

- ‘A’ has child records of type ‘B’
- ‘B’ has child records of type ‘C’

Requirement: when a user deactivates record ‘A’, ‘B’ and ‘C’ records will be deactivated automatically.

I have created two plugins on (`SetState` message, Sync, Post-Operation):

1. **setStatePluginAB**: when I deactivate an ‘A’ record, the plugin deactivates its childs which are ‘B’ records;
2. **setStatePluginBC**: when I deactivate a ‘B’ record, the plugin deactivates its childs which are ‘C’ records.

The problem is: When I deactivate an ‘A’ record, the plugin setStatePluginAB deactivates its child wich are ‘B’records, but the plugin setStatePluginBC is not triggered automatically.

How can I trigger the plugin setStatePluginBC automatically after setStatePluginAB?

Comment: Please explain how your plugin steps are registered (message names, pre/post sync/async etc.). Which `OrganizationRequest` do you use to deactivate records? Are A, B and C custom entities?

Comment: The message names is SetState and SetStateDynamicEntity, post-operation and sync. The organizationRequest used is setStateRequest tk change the states

Comment: Please provide code of setStatePluginBC.

Comment: Isn't it a viable option to set up the cascading rules to handle this instead of using code? (I know it's a silly question in a coding forum)